# Get the numeric part followed by 1 place of decimal in PostgreSQL irrespective of numeric occurance

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data is something like this

```
server      version
Server 1    5.1.42
Server 2    MySQL 5.7.16
Server 3    mysql-5.0.67-linux
Server 4    MARIADB - 10.2.9-MariaDB-log
Server 5    5.6.12-community-log
Server 6    mysql-advanced-5.6.12
Server 7    PERCONA - 5.7.19-17-log
```

My desired output will be

```
Server 1    5.1
Server 2    5.7
Server 3    5.0
Server 4    10.2
Server 5    5.6
Server 6    5.6
Server 7    5.7
```

Comment: The title says Postgresql, but there's <mysql> tag as well. Which dms are you using?

Comment: I'd be *very* wary of doing this. Version numbers are *not* decimal numbers (the existence of multiple `.`s is one clue). Version 1.20 is a *later* version number than either version 1.2 or version 1.3. Don't assume you can truncate at one "decimal" place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: in Postgres it's very easy to correctly sort on a "version string" like that correctly

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - but not if you've done what's being asked for here and *truncated* version 1.20 to version 1.2. (I assume Postgres doesn't have psychic abilities to divine what the original string was :-))

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I don't see any indication in the sample data that 1.20 should be truncated to 1.2 - the desired output simply does not include anything after the second digit.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried myself as well (below my answer). But other answers are much better and smarter. +1 everyone

Answer (score 3):

If you keep all digits of the version number (instead of just the first two), things get a lot easier:

```
select server, 
       regexp_replace(version, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g') as version_string
from data;
```

If you also want to properly *sort* by those numbers, convert the result to an integer array and sort by that:

```
select server, 
       regexp_replace(version, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g') as version_string
from data
order by string_to_array(regexp_replace(version, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g'), '.')::int[];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select server,(regexp_matches(version, '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*')) as Version
from Table1
```

OR

```
select server,(regexp_matches(version, '\d+\.?\d*')) as Version
from Table1
```

Output

```
server      version
Server 1    5.1
Server 2    5.7
Server 3    5.0
Server 4    10.2
Server 5    5.6
Server 6    5.6
Server 7    5.7
```

Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/121e2/12

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`substring(string from pattern)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function where *pattern* would be a POSIX regular expression `[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}`.

**Solution**

```
select server, substring(version from '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}') as version
from yourtable;
```

**Example**

```
select substring('MARIADB - 10.2.9-MariaDB-log' from '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}') AS output;

 output
---------
 10.2
```

**Regular expression explained:**

- `[0-9]+` matches equally or more than one characters that are numbers
- `\.` matches a dot
- `[0-9]{1}` matches equally one number

Answer (score 1):

Considering [@Damien's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555862/get-the-numeric-part-followed-by-1-place-of-decimal-in-postgresql-irrespective-o#comment86119878_49555862), I suggest this:

```
SELECT server
     , substring(version, '\d+(?:\.\d)?')  AS u_ask
     , substring(version, '\d+(?:\.\d+)?') AS u_might_need
FROM   tbl;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/deed7/2) with extended test case.

`\d` .. class shorthand for digits
`+` .. 1 or more occurrences
`?` .. 0 or 1 occurrences
`(?:re)` .. [“non-capturing” set of parentheses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried like this and works

```
SELECT "server", 
CONCAT(substring(version FROM '[0-9]+'),'.', split_part(version, '.', 2)) as newversion,
 FROM "tablename";
```